# How to put relative path anchor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, anchor

I need to implement skip link so I do:

```
<a class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#footer" target="_self">Footer</a>
```

supposed to have this link `http://localhost/example`. I want when the use click on the link this:

```
http://localhost/A#footer
```

but now I obtain this link
`http://localhost/#footer` and it gives me 404.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: I fixed a bunch of your spelling mistakes. Is the `A` in your "supposed to" URL also a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

An anchor is a link to an element id inside a specific file

```
<div id="MyDiv">...</div>
```

To go to the anchor "MyDiv" in example.html you should go to :

```
http://localhost/example.html#MyDiv
```

Comment: The question title asks for a _relative_ URL.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need a `<div id="....">` for call your page.
After it, you can call them with `#idpath` in `<a href="../index.html#idpath">Go To Path</a>`

**For Example Above**

```html
<html>
 <body>
 <a href="#yourpage3">Go to Page 3</a><br><br>
  <div id="yourpage1">
  <h1>Page Load 1</h1>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="yourpage2">
  <h1>Page Load 2</h1>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="yourpage3">
  <h1>Page Load 3</h1>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
 </body>
</html
```

Comment: @isherwood If him have a problem in **Relative Url**, so him can check in _http://foo/bar/_  because calling this route need a valid string with id `#idpath`. So if him got a 404 Error, need a recheck into _/bar/_ because we don't have a full page for any reason.

Comment: Put it in the answer, please. Don't direct it at me. :)